# Updating SQLite DB with dataframe using conditional to change column value or append new row

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas

I need to connect to an existing SQLite database, compare a key column's value to the value in a dataframe. For every key match between database and dataframe, update the value of a specific column in that row. If a key exists in the dataframe, but not in the database, append the respective row to database. The targets are relatively large datasets, so memory usage and performance is a concern (can be 20-60 gb db, @ ~20 columns and millions of rows).

I've previously tried reading the database into a dataframe and merging the old and new dataframes in memory, but that proving expensive (often a 5 gig dataset grows into 20 gigs in memory).

I'm getting lost in the logic here, and this is the farthest I've gone:

```
def update_column(tablename, key_value):
    c.execute('SELECT key FROM {}'.format(tablename))
    for row in c.fetchall():
        # populating this key value per row is challenging for me
        if row == key_value: 
            c.execute('UPDATE {} SET last_seen = {} WHERE UUID = {}}'.format(tablename, hunt_date, key_value))
        else:
            df.to_sql(table_name, if_exists='append')

for index, row in reader.iterrows():
    key_value = row['key']
    update_column(tablename, key_value)
```

Example Dataset:

Database

```
Key       First_Seen Last_Seen Data1  Data2
Bigfoot   2015       2015      Blah   Blah
Loch_Ness 2016       2016      Blah   Blah
UFO       2016       2004      Blah   Blah
```

Dataframe with new data:

```
Key       First_Seen Last_Seen Data  Data
UFO       2017       2017      Blah  Blah
Tupac     2017       2017      Blah  Blah
```

Desired output in database:

```
Key       First_Seen Last_Seen Data  Data
Bigfoot   2015       2015      Blah  Blah
Loch_Ness 2016       2016      Blah  Blah
UFO       2016       2017      Blah  Blah
Tupac     2017       2017      Blah  Blah
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested, consider a temp table in SQLite and run the  `UPDATE` and `INSERT INTO` queries. No need to iterate through the millions of rows.

Since SQLite does not support `UPDATE...JOIN`, subqueries are required such as `IN` clause. There is no harm in running append query each time as it will only append new *key* rows.

```
df.to_sql('pandastable', conn, if_exists='replace')

c.execute("UPDATE finaltable f " + \
          "SET f.last_seen = p.last_seen " + \
          "WHERE f.[key] IN (SELECT p.[key] FROM pandastable p);")
conn.commit()

c.execute("INSERT INTO finaltable ([key], first_seen, last_seen, blah, blah, blah) " + \
          "SELECT [key], first_seen, last_seen, blah, blah, blah " + \
          "FROM pandastable p " + \
          "WHERE NOT EXISTS " + \
          "   (SELECT 1 FROM finaltable sub " + \
          "    WHERE sub.[key] = p.[key]);")
conn.commit()
```

---

And if connecting pandas with [SQLAlchemy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html) instead of a raw connection, considering running action queries with transactions instead of cursor calls:

```
import sqlalchemy

...
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:sqlite:////path/to/database.db")

df.to_sql(name='pandastable', con=engine, if_exists='replace')

# SQL ACTIONS USING TRANSACTIONS
with engine.begin() as conn:     
    conn.execute("UPDATE finaltable f " + \
                 "SET f.last_seen = p.last_seen " + \
                 "WHERE f.[key] IN (SELECT p.[key] FROM pandastable p);")

with engine.begin() as conn:     
    conn.execute("INSERT INTO finaltable ([key], first_seen, last_seen, blah, blah, blah) " + \
                 "SELECT [key], first_seen, last_seen, blah, blah, blah " + \
                 "FROM pandastable p " + \
                 "WHERE NOT EXISTS " + \
                 "   (SELECT 1 FROM finaltable sub " + \
                 "    WHERE sub.[key] = p.[key]);")

engine.dispose()
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd do such an update on the SQLite side.

first save your DF as a temporary SQLite table: `tmp`:

```
df.to_sql('tmp', conn, if_exists='replace')

sql = """
UPDATE table_name set last_seen = (SELECT t.last_seen
                                   FROM tmp t
                                   WHERE t.Key = table_name.key)
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM tmp
    WHERE tmp.key = table_name.key
)
"""

c.execute(sql)
```